# Intermittent mysql database connection lost

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, azure, ubuntu-14.04

i recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on Azure VM; and 
installed MYSQL Server version: 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

VM hardware is D-Series (1 core, 3.5 GB RAM, 50 GB SSD)

My applications on another VM sometimes have delayed connection established and sometime  lose connections to this database intermittently.

I have introduced 2 variables in mysql configuration file my.cnf

```
lower_case_table_names=1
skip-name-resolve
```

.and I have commented 1 below

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

CPU seems to be running usually below 1% and peaked at 15% and max connections were 20/150.

At this point, I am clueless if this is a ubuntu problem OR a mysql related problem as I dont see any problems in the log

```
/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Any directions on how I should be checking for this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Does your app have the ability to reconnect to the database automatically?  Anything interesting in /var/log/messages?  Are you gathering [sar data](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) to review?

Comment: i am using wordpress as application (i am not sure if it does reconnect). Dont see a messages folder in /var/log. Not sure on SAR command, but I did issue a sar -o datafile interval count >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: dead end. cant seem to nail this on my own

Comment: Depending on what unix you are on, the file might be /var/log/syslog. sar is a front end to a performance tool that might be available on your system.  Run `sar -A`, is there any output?

Comment: can we pull a separate chat? skype "live:faizmh" .. I will send you details here as well

Comment: i see syslog file generated and I installed sar earlier in the day. sar -A returns tabular result

Comment: not sure how i can share results here